# Flutter: How can I position a TextButton at the end of a Listview builder instead of it being anchored at bottom of column?

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-text-button

[image]

[image]

```dart
class _AppointmentListViewState extends State<AppointmentListView> {
  int numOfInitialAppointmentsLoaded = 2;
  int numOfAppointmentsToFetch = 2;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List appointmentData = [
      ...widget.appointmentList.map(
          (appointmentData) => AppointmentModal(appointment: appointmentData))
    ];

    int totalNumberOfAppointments = appointmentData.length;

    void loadMoreAppointments() {
      if (numOfInitialAppointmentsLoaded >= totalNumberOfAppointments) {
        // may need to add a msg to the user
      } else {
        setState(() {
          if (totalNumberOfAppointments - numOfInitialAppointmentsLoaded <
              numOfAppointmentsToFetch) {
            numOfInitialAppointmentsLoaded +=
                totalNumberOfAppointments - numOfInitialAppointmentsLoaded;
          } else {
            numOfInitialAppointmentsLoaded += numOfAppointmentsToFetch;
          }
        });
      }
    }

    return Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.5,
          child: ListView.builder(
              // shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: numOfInitialAppointmentsLoaded,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return appointmentData[index];
              }),
        ),
        TextButton(
            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
              foregroundColor: cocoGypsy,
              textStyle:
                  const TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            onPressed: loadMoreAppointments,
            child: const Text("See more appointments"))
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Currently I have a list of appointments and a text button that loads more appointments. The list is generated by the Listview builder and the button is always at the bottom of the screen. How can I make the button move dynamically with the list items so that it gets pushed down as more items are loaded?

I tried removing the sized box and just have my listview and button widgets wrapped in a column, but then my appointments weren't loading at all.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```dart
return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        // shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: numOfInitialAppointmentsLoaded + 1,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          if (index == numOfInitialAppointmentsLoaded)
            return TextButton(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                foregroundColor: cocoGypsy,
                textStyle:
                    const TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              onPressed: loadMoreAppointments,
              child: const Text("See more appointments"),
            );
          return appointmentData[index];
        },
      ),
    );
```

or you can try bottom navigation bar like this

```dart
 return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
          // shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: numOfInitialAppointmentsLoaded,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return appointmentData[index];
          }),
      bottomNavigationBar: TextButton(
        style: TextButton.styleFrom(
          foregroundColor: cocoGypsy,
          textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        onPressed: loadMoreAppointments,
        child: const Text("See more appointments"),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. You can copy this source code & paste it into the `main.dart` file and run it. Don't forget to look at the attached output below the source code.

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true),
      home: const MainScreen(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 5, // try 15 here
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Card(child: ListTile(title: Text("Index $index")));
                },
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: const Text("Button"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output:
[image: output]

Comment: Thank you! This worked but it now it will load the appointments beyond the screen (on the bottom) and it won't allow me to scroll up to see them. Do you have any ideas on why that is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use CustomScrollView

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true),
      home: const IndexScreen(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class IndexScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const IndexScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverList.builder(
              itemBuilder: (cxt, index) {
                return Card(child: ListTile(title: Text("Index $index")));
              },
              itemCount: 15,
            ),
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: const Text("Button"),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```